# Worlds in development with deep background

Tags: discussion, questions

A person building a world may have put in a lot of work, written a lot of background, and then become stuck with a particular problem that depends heavily on that background.

If a problem is such that it is necessary for someone to read and understand a lot of that world's background - which may be too voluminous to post on SE without a link to a document stored elsewhere - is it still a good question for Worldbuilding SE?

Should we have - perhaps as a Community Wiki - a question that asks Worldbuilding SE users to post some details about worlds that they have created (which could be used as the background for follow-on questions)?  RPG SE has a [just-for-fun](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/just-for-fun) tag and a showcase of user-designed character sheets as a community wiki

Comment: I think something like this dilute the value of the SE format.  The value is added by not having to sort through hundreds of look at my shiny posts to find valuable questions and answers.  It invites the forum atmosphere that we try to avoid.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Questions on Stack Exchange need to be answerable and reasonably scoped.  If somebody needs to read extensive background materials before being able to answer, then that's too much to ask of the community here.  Further, it's *probably* not going to be useful to anybody else, and while Stack Exchange's goal is to answer people's real questions, it's not *just* about the asker -- we're writing for all the future people who will have the same problem and find their way here.

In asking your question it's important to share relevant background information -- my magic system works this way, or my planet has the following unusual properties, or whatever.  But you should be able to summarize the important parts of that in several paragraphs, not whole books or chapters.  And a several-paragraph explanation fits in an SE question, so there's no need to take it off-site.